# I'd like to delete a bunch of files in a folder that have a specific extension and do not match a specified string

Tags: cmd, batch-processing

I am new to command prompt scripting and batch files.  I have a folder with the following:

- file1.pdf
- file1.tif
- file1_cropped.tif
- file1.txt
- file2.pdf
- file2.tif
- file2_cropped.tif
- file2.txt...
- filen.pdf
- filen.tif
- filen_cropped.tif
- filen.txt

I would like to delete all the tif files that do not have "_cropped" in the filename.  I have seen a few solutions for deleting files that have a specified extension, or that match a specific string, but I am trying to combine the two.

Much thanks,

Marc.

Comment: To be clear: Do you want to do this from command line, or in a batch script?

Comment: Batch script is preferable, but if you are able to show examples for both that would be very helpful thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From command line, being in target directory:

```
for /F "eol=: delims=" %a in ('dir /b *.tif ^| find /V "_cropped"') do @del "%a"
```

Where we have:

```
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]
```

In batch file:

```
for /F "eol=: delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.tif ^| find /V "_cropped"') do @del "%%a"
```

---

A sample where we use a more interactive approach with confirmation:

Use typically as:

```
the_bat_file.bat exclude_these tif
```

Where option one is string in file names to exclude and two is file extension.

```
@echo off

set pat=_cropped
set ext=tif

IF "%1"=="--help"  (
    echo Usage %0 [exclude] [extension]
    echo   Default exclude  : %pat%
    echo   Default extension: %ext%
    goto end
)

GOTO part1

:confirm
SET /P CONF=Continue y/N?
IF /I "%CONF%" NEQ "Y" GOTO end
goto %con%

:part1
setlocal

IF NOT "%1"=="" set pat=%1
IF NOT "%2"=="" set ext=%2

echo Pattern  : %pat% 
echo Extension: %ext%
echo.

set con=part2
goto confirm

:part2
echo.
echo Files to delete:
echo.
for /F "eol=: delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "*.%ext%" ^| find /V "%pat%"') do echo "%%a"
echo.
set con=part3
goto confirm

:part3
for /F "eol=: delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "*.%ext%" ^| find /V "%pat%"') do DEL "%%a"

:end
endlocal
```

Comment: @laxman: You are welcome. I'm daily on Linux and it's been *long time* since I did anything batch related. Fun to catch up and got a bit carried away ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.tif^|find /v /i "_cropped"') do echo del "%%a"
```

should suit.

perhaps you'd want

```
pushd "target directoryname"
for /f "delim...
popd
```

to specify a directory other than your current to be processed.

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your great answer also.